# Double Opt In status unchanged

Tags: marketing-cloud, list

We are using lists to capture subsribers via Webcollect.
However when we activate the double opt in functionality, even though we receive the double optin confirm email and we click on the confirmation link the users' status does not change from "unsubscribed" to "active".

Any experience / tips on this?

Comment: Best add a marketing-cloud tag to your question if its this feature http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/web_collect/.

Answer (score 1):

The link in the email needs to be stack specific, you can determine the stack that you are located on by looking in the URL after logging into the Marketing Cloud UI, if after "mc" in the URL there is a value like S4, S6, S7, then that indicates the stack you are on.

The default URL for stack 1 is:

```
http://cl.exct.net/sub_confirm.asp?lst=%%List_%%&eml=%%EmailAddr_%%&mid=%%MemberID%%
```

If your account is on S7 then it would need to be:

```
http://cl.s7.exct.net/sub_confirm.asp?lst=%%List_%%&eml=%%EmailAddr_%%&mid=%%MemberID%%
```

Comment: Thanks Mac, it seems like the issue is only present for certain email addresses. The opt in works with both URLs though.